# Need an help to sort, Handle a tab seperated text file

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, arraylist

Hi i have a text file(tab seperated).

I would like to open it, read it and filter the required columns just like we do in excel. Could someone help with a sample code.

I am stuck up with the concept on how to proceed further for the below steps.

- Price has to sorted with DESC order before processing.
- Always, First two column has to be printed in the output.
- Other than the first two columns only the required column has to be printed based on the input given.
- Input will be something like (Mango/purchased/top50). so it should pick only top50 "yet to buy" under "Mango" along with its respective first two columns.

Sample input file.

```
itemNumber  Price   Mango   Apple   Bannana
112201      purchased   need to plan    purchased
112202  55  yet to buy  yet to buy  purchased
112202  67  need to plan    purchased   purchased
112203  456 need to plan    need to plan    need to plan
112203  33  need to plan    yet to buy  need to plan
112204  456 need to plan    yet to buy  need to plan
112204      yet to buy  purchased   need to plan
112205  77  yet to buy  purchased   need to plan
112205  99  yet to buy  purchased   yet to buy
112206  0   yet to buy  purchased   yet to buy
```

The code is incomplete.
Here i am trying to add the heading of the file to an arraylist and adding the content to an another arraylist. Then trying to compare them using index number. Is this way correct ?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class main {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(
                "filename.tsv.zip");

        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {

            String fruit = "Mango";
            String mappingstatus = "purchased";

            // reading a file
            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
            InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(read);

            // creating a new list
            List<String> heading = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] a = br.readLine().split("\t");
            heading = Arrays.asList(a);

            List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();

            String s;
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] b = br.readLine().split("\t");
                content = Arrays.asList(b);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? We are happy to help solve small problems and bugs, but you need to put what code you have up. We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: @mdewitt -   pasted my code.

Comment: I don't understand the expected result

Comment: @RobertoTellezIbarra - If the input is (Mango/need to plan/top50) then the result should be like the one below

`itemNumber Price Mango
112204 456 need to plan
112206 456 need to plan
112203 67 need to plan
112205 33 need to plan`

Comment: I suggest you use an Excel file instead of a tab separated text file, and use Apache POI

Comment: @HuangChen - Sorry i am forced to use text file here.

Comment: All items have price?

Comment: No all items doesn't have a price. We can change the null as zero for easy sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class Item implements Comparable<Item> {

    int itemNumber;
    int price;
    String mango;
    String apple;
    String bannana;

    public Item(int itemNumber, int price, String mango, String apple, String bannana) {
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
        this.price = price;
        this.mango = mango;
        this.apple = apple;
        this.bannana = bannana;
    }

    //GETTERS

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item compareItem) {
        int comparePrice = ((Item) compareItem).getPrice();
        //ascending order
        //return this.price - comparePrice;

        //descending order
        return comparePrice - this.price;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    //populate the items list by creating an Item for every line you read.
    //Handle null price values
    Collections.sort(items);

    //assuming input is some like 'Mango/purchased/top50'
    String input = "Mango/purchased/top50";
    String[] parts = input.split("/");
    int max = Integer.parseInt(parts[2].substring(3));

    List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size() && result.size() < max; i++) {
        Item item = items.get(i);
        if ((parts[0].equals("Mango") && item.getMango().equals(parts[1]))
                || (parts[0].equals("Apple") && item.getApple().equals(parts[1]))
                || (parts[0].equals("Bannana") && item.getBannana().equals(parts[1]))) {
            result.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Complete the commented sections and it must work. More references about sorting here: [Sorting](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)